# Find the lowest value within a custom range in an array

Tags: python, arrays, min

I have an array say `numbers = [4,4,9,2,3]` and I want to to find the lowest value within a custom range.

Range of index `2`, I want the lowest value from `[4, 4, 9]`.

so far, I have:

```
min(range(numbers[2))
```

Comment: so far, what you have looks to be invalid syntax. also, the word you're looking for (a custom range in array) is slicing.

Comment: `min(numbers[:2])`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use range, arrays already support slicing through subscripts:

```
min(numbers[:3])
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't know this existed